# Error message not showing and hiding depending on if else statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, html-table, show-hide

I have a function that loops through all of the inputs of my form and checks if they are filled or not. If the field is blank, it makes that specific input pink and returns false.

I'm trying to add a "Field Required" message underneath the inputs that are not filled. So i coded an extra table row after each one, with a div that holds the error message. The css for the div is set to "display:none" on page load.

Right now my function is showing "required" for every input and not just the ones that are blank, but the pink coloring is still working correctly.

How do I get the "required" div to show and hide correctly like the pink coloring does?

```
checkinputs = function (blockOne,blockTwo) {
inputGood = true;
blOne = $(blockOne);
blTwo = $(blockTwo);
blInput = [blOne,blTwo];
for (x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
        var validators = blInput[x].find(" [id$='RequiredIndicator']").parent().parent('tr').find(':input:not(:hidden)');
        var notAllFilled = validators.filter(function(){
        var myInput = $(this); //.parent().parent('tr').find(':input');
        var filledVal = myInput.val();
        var isFilled = $.trim(filledVal).length;
            if (isFilled) {
                $(this).css('background-color', 'white');

                $(this).closest('div').find('.required').hide();

                $(this).parent('td').prev('td').find('span').text('*'); 
                }
            else {
            $(this).css('background-color', 'pink');

            $(this).closest('div').find('.required').show();

             $(this).parent('td').prev('td').find('span').text('*');            
            inputGood = false;  
            }
        return isFilled;
        }).length;
    var inputCount = validators.length;
};
    if( !inputGood ){
        $('#errorAlert').append('<span style="font-weight:bold;">"Some required    information is missing. Please complete the missing fields below."</span>' + '<br><br>');
        $('#errorAlertTwo').append('<span style="font-weight:bold;">"Some required credit card information is missing. Please complete the missing fields below."</span>' + '<br><br>');    
    }
    return inputGood;   
};
```

HERE IS A FIDDLE OF THE ISSUE:
http://jsfiddle.net/RNMM7/

Comment: please show your html markup, also show complete js code, what is $(this) referring to?

Comment: If you can make a fiddle, it would be even better!

Comment: This javascript code is meaningless without HTML. Post your HTML too

Comment: Sorry, added a fiddle of the issue!

Comment: Damn, my Fiddle isn't firing the function like it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is almost definitely your line to show the div:

```
$(this).closest('div').find('.required').show();
```

What this line does is:

1. Starting at your $(this), it finds the nearest ancestor [including $(this)] that is a div, going up the DOM tree
2. Finds all elements with class 'required' under that div, and shows them.

Without seeing how your HTML is structured, my guess is that the nearest div element up the DOM tree encompasses all your .required elements.  You'd need to replace the 'div' in that statement with an element lower in the DOM tree that would only encompass your $(this) and the one .required element you want to show.

Comment: that makes allot of sense, i think this is probably the issue. I added a fiddle of the code so you can see how the html is structured

Comment: Doesn't look like the fiddle is working exactly right - the easiest way may be to add a class like .field_holder to the td element that has the label, the input, and the div, and use `$(this).closest('.field_holder').find('.required').show();`

Comment: unfortunately the required div is not in the same td as the input. each required label is in the next row, and three td's over. How would i target that?

Comment: Find the first common parent of the input field and the div to put the new class in.  (I thought that happened to also be a td element but I may have misread it).